# Versioning for deployments of microservices in lagom on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sbt, microservices, lagom

Question is related to deployment of micro services .

Framework used -- Lagom .

Suppose i Have two microservices Say M1,M2 which is in same git repository . 
So we have only one build.sbt and both microservices are define in that build.sbt  .

Now when we deploy these microsevices on kubernetes we have to make docker images with some tag . 
I will give the Tag name of docker image , the version of microservices  .

Now , i have two options for defining versions of microservices  .

```
     1. One is for every commit i will update versions of both microservices say 1.1 , 1.2 and so on .... , (here i have to increase version of both microservices as i do not know that for which microservice commit is done as repo is same for two microservices . )
```

I am using single repo as recommended by lagom doc Build Philosophy as we have very small team  .

```
     2. developer has to increase version in build.sbt  every time he commit a feature or bug fix .
```

Now My question/Doubt is  as follows

```
     1.How should generally people manage version in this case . 
     2.There may be many bug fixes daily , so i do not want to update version on every small bug fix . 
     3.How to manage compatibility between microservices version .
```

What lagom suggest what are the best practices for all above problems.

Comment: You asked about 6 questions in one question and they are mostly about patterns and practices than about programming or technical things. I'm so sorry but don't expect any answer to this.

Comment: i will break it in parts and post as different questions.